# Get longitude latitude from address using OpenStreetMaps?

Tags: c#, openstreetmap

I'm using OpenStreetMaps + Itinero to route and play with longitude and latitude coordinates. I selected a specific area in OSM and saved it to a file. Thing is, I don't know if these long/lat coords can also be mapped to addresses. Do we know if this is possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible. If you´re asking on "how", this will be way too broad for StackOverflow. Post what you´ve tried already and where *specifically* you´re stuck, not just "how do I do this". For start search for "find adress to location", AKA geo-locating.

Comment: Hi HimBromBeere, I don't actually know where to start on this. I've got the OSM/PBF file and I'm creating an app where you can search addresses on a map. I have a database of long/lats of the area, in the C# code a message box will come up asking to enter postcode and house number. I want to be able to search long/lats that I have based on the postcode and house number... but given the pbf i have (which doesn't include address, just long/lats) i'm not sure how I can do this.